# How to use append a line in xml file?

Tags: xml, perl

Input:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<category cname='Cname1' id='c1'>
  <subcat key='3' sname='Subname1' sid='sid1'>
    <prod key='1' pname='Productname'>value1</prod>
  </subcat>
</category>
</root>
```

output should be mentioned below:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <root>
    <category cname='Cname1' id='c1'>
      <subcat key='3' sname='Subname1' sid='sid1'>
        <prod key='1' pname='Productname'>value1</prod>
        **<prod key='2' pname='Productname1'>value2</prod>**
      </subcat>
    </category>
    </root>
```

I have used File::Slurp module to append this one. But i want to use Xml::Simple or Xml::Twig for getting this output.

Please help me to get this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "But i want to use Xml::Simple or Xml::Twig for getting this output." - well, go ahead and use them. What specific problem are you having doing so?

Comment: XML is structured data. Use an XML manipulation library. That is, *start there* - not with slurping or direct text-based oprations.

Comment: @Mat in my input i have to match a corresponding Category name, sub cat name for this operation. In my file contain many sub categories. I have to identify the below order
Category -> Sub Category -> append a new line

Comment: Yes, and? What have you tried so far? Where is your actual problem?

Comment: @Mat I have no idea to use Xml::Simple or Xml::Twig. I have tried using File::Slurp module.

Comment: The go read the docs and search for examples/tutorials for "perl xml".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  pretty_print  => 'indented',
  twig_handlers => {

    # When we get to the end of a <root> or <category> element,
    # output everything we've processed so far.
    'root|category'  => sub { $_[0]->flush },

    # When a <subcat> element is encountered...
    'subcat' => sub {
      # Create a new element
      my $new = XML::Twig::Elt->new(
        "prod",
        {
          key   => 1,
          pname => "Productname1",
        },
        "value2",
      );
      # Insert it at the end...
      $new->paste(after => $_->last_child);
    },
  },
);
$twig->parse(\*DATA);

__DATA__
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<category cname='Cname1' id='c1'>
  <subcat key='3' sname='Subname1' sid='sid1'>
   <prod key='1' pname='Productname'>value1</prod>
  </subcat>
</category>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, provided you have all the data about the new product already available, including where it should be inserted in the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $p= { category => 'Cname1', subcat => '3', 
         key => '2', pname => 'Productname1', value => 'value2'
       };

# XPath selecting the appropriate subcat
my $change= qq{category[\@cname="$p->{category}"]/subcat[\@key="$p->{subcat}"]};

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { $change => sub { new_product( @_, $p); } },
                pretty_print => 'indented'
              )
          ->parsefile( 'products.xml')
          ->print;

sub new_product
  { my( $t, $subcat, $p)= @_;
    $subcat->insert_new_elt( last_child => prod => 
                              { pname => $p->{pname}, key => $p->{key} },
                              $p->{value}
                           );
  }
```

Comment: that's way too much information

Comment: pls share the full code..

Comment: How am I supposed to know what the category and subcategories are? Only you know this. I gave you the bit that updates the XML. you have to create the `$p` record with the data you want. I can't do this for you.